# How can i make a sticky sidebar for a wordpress site?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can i make a sticky sidebar for a wordpress website? My problem is sidebar sticks but i can't scroll or use my all widget on that sticky sidebar. i can just access two widgets on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a container for your sidebar content with those settings :

```
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: whateverYouNeedpx;
```

Then another container with something like this :

```
position: relative;
height: 100%;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

You should then be able to scroll if the navbar content overflows the height.